# 辞書のvalueが２つ以上の要素を持つオブジェクトかどうか知りたい

Tags: python

辞書のvalueが２つ以上の要素を持っているかどうか知りたいです。
今、

```
df = {"A": {"a1": 0.5}} #1
df = {"A": {"e1": 1.6, "f1": 2.0}} #2
df = {"A": {"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}} #3
```

という辞書が３つあります。
valueが１つ（例えば、`{"A": {"a1": 0.5}}`）なら、if文の中でAの処理をし、
valueが２つ以上（例えば、`{"A": {"e1": 1.6, "f1": 2.0}}`・`{"A": {"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}}`）なら、if文の中でBの処理をする、という流れにしたいです。

```
if len(df.values()) != 1:
   B(df)
else:
   A(df)
```

とコードを書いたのですが、#1の辞書も#2・#3の辞書もどちらもdf.values()が１であると判定されてしまいます。
どのように判定できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**全て1だと判定される原因**
全てのvalues()は、以下のように取得されてしまいます。

```
df = {"A": {"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}}
df.values()
>dict_values([{'b1': 1.0, 'c1': 1.5, 'd1': 1.9}])

len(df.values())
>1
```

結局、全部長さが1だからです。
なぜ、この長さが全部１かというと、dfの値が一つのディクショナリだと判定されるからです。

**仮定 もし値をもう一つ増やすと**

```
df = {"A": {"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9},"B":{"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}}

In [19]:len(df.values())
Out[19]: 2
```

この場合は、2つのディクショナリがあるので、2とカウントされます。
pypyさんの書いた`df = {"A": {"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}}`だと、
`df`の中には、一つのディクショナリしかないからです。`df`には"A"というキーが入っており、その値として、 {"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}が入れられているんだけれども、df.values()の長さを調べようとすると、{"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}というdict型の値が一つ入っているとカウントされています。
　なので、`{"b1": 1.0, "c1": 1.5, "d1": 1.9}`の長さを調べたいというのであれば、`df.values()`の長さではなく、`"A"`というキーで指定された値の長さを調べなくてはなりません。
おそらく、されようとしているのはそうしたことでしょうから、`key`を指定してあげるといいです。

```
In [10]:df["A"]
Out[10]: {'b1': 1.0, 'c1': 1.5, 'd1': 1.9}

In [10]:len(df["A"])
Out[11]: 3
```

**提案**
よって、

```
if len(df["A"]) != 1:
   B(df)
else:
   A(df)
```

がいいんじゃないでしょうか。